# How reliable is Bluetooth BLE in combination with smartphones?

Tags: authentication, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, smartphone

We are developing a system where we can open doors with a smartphone. The chosen technique for this is Bluetooth BLE. There is an app which needs to be active in the background for providing this “handles key system”. This app recognizes and connects automatically with the door to open it.

We have a working demo on 3 different iphone models and several different android phones. The exact details of these system are not important for my question.

For our project we are in talk with some investors who says the idea is great but the Bluetooth technique is not reliable enough.  The don’t say on what point it isn’t reliable enough.

We need to prove that Bluetooth IS reliable for this situation so we are looking for some best practices where Bluetooth is uses in critical situation such as a transport or health sector. Some “official” papers from a professors or university is also welcome!

We also looking aslo for examples where comparable situations where locks or something else are opened “handless” with a smartphone. 
Where can we find these information, firms, papers and so on? In one line: How can we prove that Bluetooth is stable and reliable for our purposal (using a smartphone which autoconnects to some device for authentication)

I hope someone can help us else our project will be canceled!

Comment: There a ton of them. Did you even look ? http://www.bestbuy.com/site/home-security-safety/smart-door-locks/pcmcat308100050017.c?id=pcmcat308100050017

Comment: Offcourse we looked but we need serveral points that are scientifically researched and proven. We can't easly say "there are a lot of other firms that use bluetooth". We can't find some scientifically proven situations or documentation of stituations. And out of the key systems in the link we can't find other "critical" situations where bluetooth is used for. Thats the reason why i asked this here. Thanks anyway

Comment: I think it is virtually impossible to prove "scientifically" - It is a bit difficult if the investors won't give you a specific concern which you can address.  As you have found, BLE works.  Can you guarantee that it will work 100% of the time?  No, because there are too many variables; the user could turn off Bluetooth.  They could terminate the app or restart their phone and not re-launch the app.

Comment: Even if you had some research paper that said "we did this and it worked every time", it would only be valid for that specific phone with a specific firmware version communicating with specific BLE peripheral chipset with specific firmware.  Change any of those things and you are back to "it should work and it seems to work".  You can't really extrapolate from any other experience with any other software/hardware beyond general statements.  You have to prove that *your hardware* and *your software* is reliable.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the BLE technology itself regarding reliability. It's rather the hardware and software implementations that will define how reliable a solution will be.

After having worked with BLE for several years I can tell that most peripheral SoC solutions are very reliable. And if they for some reason crash, the firmware is usually rebooted and restored.

Android and iOS are often the ones to blame if something isn't reliable. The Bluetooth stack running on these OSes crash quite often or misbehave and it can be hard to recover from.

For Android, sometimes Bluetooth crashes and when you try to turn it on again in it just goes back to turned off state. To recover you have to reboot the phone. I must however say that if you manage to initiate a connection and don't get any errors it will often continue to run correctly. To avoid the Android system to kill your app while it's in the background you have to use a foreground service. On some phones, like Huawei, the user must also explicitly mark the app to not being killed by the system when it's running in the background. For Android, there are also many phones with different Bluetooth controllers and some have bugs other controllers don't have. For example I once got hand on a Sony Xperia Z3 phone which Bluetooth controller cancelled a pending connection when an LE scan (running in parallel) was cancelled, but according to the HCI log the pending connection was still going on. The peripheral was advertising but was never connected to the phone. Once the pending connection was explicitly cancelled and restarted, it connected immediately.

iOS is more problematic than Android if you want BLE to work in the background. iOS will kill your app when it has been in the background for some time. To get around that, they have something called "state preservation" which is their solution to wake up the app on an incoming Bluetooth event such as the peripheral connects or sends a notification. However there are many bugs and design decisions which will lead to that your app isn't being woken up. For example see https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/65953. If your app has been terminated and the user turns off and then turns on bluetooth (or the system restarts bluetooth due to internal errors), your app will not be woken up on an incoming Bluetooth event. Also, if a bug occurs in the Bluetooth stack (which happens quite frequently), your app will not be woken up and all the events will rather arrive to your app once the user manually opens it up.

Comment: Thankyou Emil. This is the answer I was looking for, re iOS: "Also, if a bug occurs in the Bluetooth stack (which happens quite frequently) ..."